# Could not find method dataBinding() for arguments on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting 
"Could not find method dataBinding() for arguments on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."  while adding databinding{enable = true} to app gradle file. Didnt find any solution in stackflow.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ex1"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: That goes in the `android` closure. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start.html).

Comment: Thanks ,I just followed specified docs but same issue .  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
Is there any additional dependecy I need to add

Comment: It would help if we could see the entire `build.gradle` file. The "edit" link below the question lets you edit your question -- you could paste the `build.gradle` file contents into the question.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 3):

See the link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start

You should set the following:

```
dataBinding {
enabled = true }
```

inside the android section, before the closing brace. So it will fix the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You must use the dataBinding section **inside the the android section** like the following

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment, the `databinding` closure goes **inside** the `android` closure. Your current `build.gradle` file has it **outside** the `android` closure.

So, switch to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ex1"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```